# Can't get scrollbar-gutter to work on bottom scrollbar

Tags: css

Whenever I add the property to an `overflow-x: auto` div, it only adds the gutter to the right side.

I added `scrollbar-gutter: stable` to a div with `overflow-x: auto` and expected the gutter to be added to the bottom but it was only added to the right side.

Here is a minimally recreatable scenario, the hide and show buttons are just for seeing that it doesn't work as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/5mc9vqwg/65/

My goal is to maintain alignment between label and input. The overall look and feel cannot change since we have a client who wants it this way.

Good, labels aligned with inputs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOk3C.png

Bad, labels misaligned because everything is shift by scrollbar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynl3W.png

My idea was to add bottom scrollbar gutter to both parts (labels and inputs) so there's equal spacing at the bottom always, even when scrollbar is shown/hidden.

My current workaround is doing a 180 degree x-transform on the container, then on the immediate child, which essentially puts the bottom scrollbar at the top. That way, when it gets shoved down, my justify-end labels don't misalign with the inputs.

```html
<div class="d-flex gap-3">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column pb-3 flex-shrink-0 justify-end gap-3" style="height: 200x;">
    <span style="height: 21px;">input label 1</span>
    <span style="height: 21px;">input label 2</span>
    <span style="height: 21px;">input label 3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex gap-3 pa-1" style="overflow-x: auto; scrollbar-gutter: stable both-edges;">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 pa-2 repeated-section-width" style="border: 2px solid black;">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
        item info 1
        <br>
        item info 2
        <br>
        item info 3
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-3">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 pa-2 repeated-section-width" style="border: 2px solid black;">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
        item info 1
        <br>
        item info 2
        <br>
        item info 3
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-3">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide-me d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 pa-2 repeated-section-width" style="border: 2px solid black;">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
        item info 1
        <br>
        item info 2
        <br>
        item info 3
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-3">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide-me d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 pa-2 repeated-section-width" style="border: 2px solid black;">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
        item info 1
        <br>
        item info 2
        <br>
        item info 3
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-3">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide-me d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 pa-2 repeated-section-width" style="border: 2px solid black;">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
        item info 1
        <br>
        item info 2
        <br>
        item info 3
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-3">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide-me d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 pa-2 repeated-section-width" style="border: 2px solid black;">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
        item info 1
        <br>
        item info 2
        <br>
        item info 3
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-3">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<button onclick="hide()">hide</button>
<button onclick="show()">show</button>
```

```css
@for $i from 0 through 16 {
  .gap-#{$i} {
    gap: #{$i * 4}#{"px"} !important;
  }
}

@for $i from 0 through 16 {
  .pb-#{$i} {
    padding-bottom: #{$i * 4}#{"px"} !important;
  }
}

@for $i from 0 through 16 {
  .pa-#{$i} {
    padding: #{$i * 4}#{"px"} !important;
  }
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-shrink-0 {
  flex-shrink: 0
}

.flex-shrink-1 {
  flex-shrink: 1
}

.justify-end {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

$repeated-section-width: 170px;

.repeated-section-width {
  width: $repeated-section-width;
}
```

```js
function hide() {
  for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('.hide-me')) el.style.display = 'none';
}

function show() {
  for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('.hide-me')) el.style.display = 'unset';
}
```

Comment: What's the HTML & CSS you have until now, for us to see this issue in action?

Comment: I added a minimally recreatable fiddle link.

Comment: Could you share an image too of how it supposed to look like?

Comment: I've added two images.

Comment: I've posted my workaround. You may take a look on my answer.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] **in your question** not on a third party site

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
scrollbar-gutter: stable both-edges
```

Comment: I tried this, too, but it added it to the left and right.

Comment: Are you setting the width? Also if you could show some example code that would also help

Comment: I added a minimally recreatable fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you're in better need of *hiding the scrollbar while keeping the scroll functionality*.

For this, the CSS you need is this:

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
html {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

In action:

```js
function hide() {
  for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('.hide-me')) el.style.display = 'none';
}

function show() {
  for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('.hide-me')) el.style.display = 'unset';
}
```

```css
@for $i from 0 through 16 {
  .gap-#{$i} {
    gap: #{$i * 4}#{"px"} !important;
  }
}

@for $i from 0 through 16 {
  .pb-#{$i} {
    padding-bottom: #{$i * 4}#{"px"} !important;
  }
}

@for $i from 0 through 16 {
  .pa-#{$i} {
    padding: #{$i * 4}#{"px"} !important;
  }
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-shrink-0 {
  flex-shrink: 0
}

.flex-shrink-1 {
  flex-shrink: 1
}

.justify-end {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

$repeated-section-width: 170px;

.repeated-section-width {
  width: $repeated-section-width;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
html {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex gap-3">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column pb-3 flex-shrink-0 justify-end gap-3" style="height: 200x;">
    <span style="height: 21px;">input label 1</span>
    <span style="height: 21px;">input label 2</span>
    <span style="height: 21px;">input label 3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex gap-3 pa-1" style="overflow-x: auto; scrollbar-gutter: stable both-edges;">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 pa-2 repeated-section-width" style="border: 2px solid black;">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
        item info 1
        <br>
        item info 2
        <br>
        item info 3
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-3">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 pa-2 repeated-section-width" style="border: 2px solid black;">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
        item info 1
        <br>
        item info 2
        <br>
        item info 3
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-3">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide-me d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 pa-2 repeated-section-width" style="border: 2px solid black;">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
        item info 1
        <br>
        item info 2
        <br>
        item info 3
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-3">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide-me d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 pa-2 repeated-section-width" style="border: 2px solid black;">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
        item info 1
        <br>
        item info 2
        <br>
        item info 3
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-3">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide-me d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 pa-2 repeated-section-width" style="border: 2px solid black;">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
        item info 1
        <br>
        item info 2
        <br>
        item info 3
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-3">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide-me d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 pa-2 repeated-section-width" style="border: 2px solid black;">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 8px;">
        item info 1
        <br>
        item info 2
        <br>
        item info 3
      </div>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column gap-3">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<button onclick="hide()">hide</button>
<button onclick="show()">show</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the users still want to see and be able to click the scrollbar itself.